# $\mathbb{Z}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]/I$ is a field therefore it's finite

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I'd spent much time for this but didn't get any results..
Could u give me only the idea but not a full proof

Comment: If you don't precise what is $I$ the statement is trivially false.

Comment: $I$ is ideal(maximal in case factor is a field) or what do u mean?
Could u give a counterexample please

Comment: Is the hypothesis that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I$ is a field?

Comment: Yes it is: thats a field $\implies$ finiteness

Comment: @N.H. There is no need to precise anything else than $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbf{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Comment: I just gave you the idea, and left you the last funny bit to prove. ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen : I didn't understood that "$\mathbb Z[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ is a field" was in the hypothesis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed true. Suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbf{Z}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ and that $A :=\mathbf{Z}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]/I$ is a field (so that $I$ is maximal ideal of $\mathbf{Z}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$) and note $f : \mathbf{Z}\to A$  the unique morphism of rings from $\mathbf{Z}$ to $A$. Its kernel is an strict (because this morphism is not the zero morphism !) ideal of $\mathbf{Z}$ whose ideals are $(0)$ and $(p)$ for $p$ prime. Imagine that we have shown that it is not $(0)$ but a $(p)$ for $p$ prime. Then $A$ is a field extension of $\mathbf{F}_p$ such that $A = \mathbf{F}_p [u_1,\ldots,u_n]$ where $u_i$ is the image of $x_i$ in $A$. This *implies* that all $u_i$ are *algebraic* over $\mathbf{F}_p$, and that the extension $A$ is of *finite degree* that we note $d$, so that $A$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbf{F}_p)^d$ as $\mathbf{F}_p$-vector space, and is of cardinal $p^d$, and is indeed *finite*. Now, to conclude, we need to show that the kernel cannot be equal to $(0)$. Then $f$ extends to a (necessarily injective) morphism of fields $F : \mathbf{Q}\to A$. Note that if $u_i$ is the image of $x_i$ in $A$, we have $A = \mathbf{Z}[u_{1},\dots,u_{n}] = \mathbf{Q}[u_{1},\dots,u_{n}]$ and as this is a field, it implies that each $u_i$ is in fact algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$, and $A$ is an extension of finite degree of $\mathbf{Q}$ (through $F$). Now each $u_i$ has a minimal polynomial over $\mathbf{Q}$, write all its coefficient as irreductible fractions, and note $d_i$ the product of all denominators of these fractions, and finally note $d$ the product of the $d_i$'s. Then $A$ is integral over $B=\mathbf{Z}\left[\frac{1}{d}\right]$. Which implies that $\mathbf{Q}$ is integral over $B$, which implies (as $Q$ is a field) that $B$ is a field, which is a contradicticon.

For a  more conceptual proof, you can look for the so-called Zariski's lemma. See the discussion here :

[If a ring is Noetherian, then every subring is finitely generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94952/if-a-ring-is-noetherian-then-every-subring-is-finitely-generated)

Comment: Ideal of canonical inclusion is not $(0)$ because otherwise $\mathbb{Q}$ is subfield of $A$, but $A$ is finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is not.

Comment: You mean "is not $(0)$" ? If so, that's the right argument, yes. ;-)

Comment: I will edit my answer

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: It's curious how you can find related links, but not the original question.

Comment: What do you mean ? Ah ok, if I understand what you mean : because I remember that there was a discussion on Zariski's lemma in such a question, so I looked for it.

Answer (score 4):

First we need to show the kernel of $f:\mathbb Z\to K:=\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ contains some prime number $p$. Suppose not, then we have an inclusion of rings $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Q\subset K$. Since $K$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra, it is also a finitely generated $\mathbb Q$-algebra. By [Zariski's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma), $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$. In other words, $K$ is a finite $\mathbb Q$-module. Also $K$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra. This implies $\mathbb Q$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra (by Proposition 14.2 in Sharp, *Steps in Comuutative Algebra*), which is nonsense.

Now knowing that $I$ contain some prime number $p$, so we can quotient out $(p)$ to get $K=\mathbb F_p[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\bar I$, which is a finitely generated $\mathbb F_p$-algebra. Apply [Zariski's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma) again, we know $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb F_p$, which is a finite field.

Comment: I found your answer on the site while searching my own question, and I understood it almost completely, except for the following: why is nonsense that $\mathbb{Q}$ to be a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra?

I believe it, but how to prove it? I'm asking here to avoid to create another post. Thanks.

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba It's Euclid's argument $1/(b_1\cdots b_n+1)\notin\mathbb Z[a_1/b_1,\dots,a_n/b_n]$.